# My audio stopped working suddenly in Debian/i3wm/alsa/pulseaudio

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, i3

Once after i rebooted my laptop, my sound just stopped to work since then. I've already search a lot of solutions, the common solutions didn't suit my case.

> - The auto-mute mode is disabled in alsamixer.
> - The driver is currently loaded.
> - There aren't any mute button selected in pavucontrol, and I've already tried to change between all profile available there.
> - I've already removed the files of `.config/pulse/` and started the service again.
> - When any sound application is running as spotify or firefox, in pavucontrol the visualizer bar of the application reacts, bouncing up and down.

The only thing strange that I have noticed, it was the `pulseaudio -vvvv --log-time=1` output raising **pa_pid_file_create() failed**. However the `pulseaudio` seems to be working fine.

```
(   0.000|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
(   0.000|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
(   0.000|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
(   0.005|   0.005) D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 10.0
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/pulseaudio-ZMrhzG/pulseaudio-10.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u1 (2018-08-03)
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is c32fd4b4661649caa3522bccc1cb42f0.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 1.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/rafa/.config/pulse.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
(   0.005|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
(   0.005|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

My configurations:

`pactl info` output:

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 32
Server Protocol Version: 32
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 16
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: rafa
Host Name: rafa
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 10.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
Cookie: 6573:78a6
```

`lspci -vvv` output:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 280
    Region 0: Memory at d5320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at d5300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

`dmesg | grep 00:1f.3` output:

```
[    0.228974] pci 0000:00:1f.3: [8086:9d70] type 00 class 0x040300
[    0.228995] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd5320000-0xd5323fff 64bit]
[    0.229020] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x20: [mem 0xd5300000-0xd530ffff 64bit]
[    0.229067] pci 0000:00:1f.3: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.229203] pci 0000:00:1f.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    2.766555] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.845342] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.984520] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
[    5.985440] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
[    5.985500] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards` output:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xd5320000 irq 280
```

`aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3234 Analog [ALC3234 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux rafa 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u1 (2018-08-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`OS`: Debian-9.5
`i3 --version`:4.13

**UPDATE:**
After all, I decided to use the brute force and I removed all packages from alsa and pulseaudio, and I installed it again. After a reboot, It is working back again.